# Archived app crashes only on iOS 5.1 not on 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have archived my app and given for testing.

when i run this app , I dont find any crash on ios5 Version.( i dont have 5.1 device)
But my client has 5.1 version, when he tried he got crash when tapping on some button inside the app.

So i have asked him the crash report which look as below

```
Date/Time:       2012-04-23 12:54:10.320 +1000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B179)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x3788488f 0x35d8a259 0x37884789 0x378847ab 0x38037a1b 0x9451 0x2493b 0x33f69e33 0x33f76391 0x33f76201 0x33f760e7 0x33f75969 0x33f756ab 0x33f69ca7 0x33f6997d 0xb397 0xc21f 0x3408f3cb 0x377de3fd 0x33f4bfaf 0x33f4bf6b 0x33f4bf49 0x33f4bcb9 0x33f4c5f1 0x33f4aad3 0x33f4a4c1 0x33f3083d 0x33f300e3 0x326e822b 0x37858523 0x378584c5 0x37857313 0x377da4a5 0x377da36d 0x326e7439 0x33f5ee7d 0x25f7 0x25b0)

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35d0332c 0x35cf2000 + 70444
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31e51208 0x31e04000 + 315912
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31e4a298 0x31e04000 + 287384
    3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35456f64 0x35450000 + 28516
    4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35454346 0x35450000 + 17222
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35d8a350 0x35d81000 + 37712
    6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x354543be 0x35450000 + 17342
    7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3545444a 0x35450000 + 17482
    8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3545581e 0x35450000 + 22558
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35d8a2a2 0x35d81000 + 37538
    10  CoreFoundation                  0x377da506 0x377cb000 + 62726
    11  CoreFoundation                  0x377da366 0x377cb000 + 62310
    12  GraphicsServices                0x326e7432 0x326e3000 + 17458
    13  UIKit                           0x33f5ee76 0x33f2d000 + 204406
    14  MyApp                           0x000025f0 0x1000 + 5616
    15  MyApp                           0x000025a8 0x1000 + 5544
```

When i do debug the crash report in terminal,

> armv7 0x000025f0 main (in MyApp) (main.m:14)
>
> armv7 0x000025a8 start (in MyApp) + 32

But i am not sure what it describes , please let me know that what it explains

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The only solution is to execute it on a 5.1 simulator or device and look how it works, I noticed that every time Apple release a new version of iOS I have to change something in my code (not much) in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT is the most generic type of crash. If you are running say an iPhone 3gs and your client is using a newer iPhone 4/4s for example you could be compiling for different architectures (Armv6/7) make sure its set to Armv6 in that case and it also looks like one of the methods you are using may be deprecated. Look for code in main.m. There are a lot of instances where you have to use iOS version difference code (but most of it is for iOS4/iOS5)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. can you please tell me what i need to do now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was using core data in my app, so if you are using core data, maybe this answer will help you, I fixed mine by changing the `persistentStoreCoordinator` store code.

```
    ....
    - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

        if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
            return persistentStoreCoordinator;
        }

        NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingFormat:@"yourdb.sqlite"]] ;
    ....
```

Check this line

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingFormat:@"yourdb.sqlite"]] ;
```

Changed the above line to

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourdb.sqlite"]] ;
```

This just solved my problem.